# My admob ad don't show

Tags: android

I found tutorials and solution but I still don't know how to show my admob ad.

It just show the webview and a white area below.

Below is my activity that show admob below a webview.

I do it follow youtube tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzTFkpIj2L4

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ContentActivity" >
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/webview_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a1526xxxxxadunitidxxxxe141f8"
    ads:loadOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="DEVICE_ID" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your manifest file

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"        
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Comment: It into <application> tag and below 2 activity "Main Activity" and "Content Activity", Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to get started is looking at the admob documentation. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

Comment: Make sure that you have an internet to get the ads and you need two permissions for that (INTERNET & ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)